# PrimeReact: Semantic colors in CheckBox or custom components

Tags: primereact

I would like to be able to use the colors PrimeReact is using for info, warning, error etc.

In my custom components, how would I reference those colors, via CSS or classes.

To be more precise, I am looking to change the color of a checkbox from primary to warning. I know I can set it the hex value, or even --var of some yellow color. But I want it to be the 'warning' color so when switching themes, the color is updated appropriately.

Does PrimeReact even support this kind of thing?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently no.

Actually a nice feature suggestion on PrimeReact GitHub would be to expose the info, warning, and error colors as CSS vars so you could do something like...

```css
color: var(--warning-color)
```

or something like that.